# Is it possible to give a JSP page variables?

Tags: java, jsp

I would like to know if I can add custom variables to the context of a JSP page.

For example, you can use `out` instead of `System.out`, is this also possible with own variables so I can use something like `myApplication.getVersion()`?
Or is there another library for doing this?

Comment: I suggest that you create application-scoped variables. Those variables could be set in a Servlet's init method that reads your data from a properties file. That Servlet could be configured to be loaded on start-up of your web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with JSTL tag `c:set`.

```
<c:set var="application" scope="session" value="${requestScope.myApplication}"/>
```

Then you could call any method like `${application.getVersion()}`.

---

```
<jsp:useBean id="name" scope="request" type="your.package.Class"/>
```

Alternatively, you may use bean definition and refer to the object as `${name}`.

Comment: OK sorry I think this might not be the exact thing.
I already have a server application doing some stuff and now I want a web backend which can display information like the connected clients and other custom things. So I need to have access to the current instance of the server class in the JSP page.

Comment: @Kage0x3B, you should pass your needed instances as request parameters and here (on the jsp page) you may get them through `requestScope`. Currently, jsp page knows nothing about server instances.